# Continous receiving & sending on a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on assignment where I need to connect to a server (no details of server are disclosed), capture the reply, modify it and send it back for verification.

I have created following code which does what I need, but the issue is that after 1st correct reply, server sends another.

Code:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
from decryptmsg import decryptmsg
from cleanmsg import cleanmsg

#connection 
ip="<IP>"
port=4000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip,port))

def recvall(sock):
    BUFFER = 8192
    data = b''
    while True:
        part = sock.recv(BUFFER)
        data += part
        if len(part) < BUFFER:
            break
    return data


while True:

    print "[+] start communication"
    data = recvall(sock)
    print data
    data = cleanmsg(data)
    if data != None:
        valmis = decryptmsg(str(data))
        if valmis == None:
            print "[-] no results"
            break
        else:
            print "[+] sending message... "
            sock.send(valmis) 
            continue
```

When I hit the second question, I get the input captured fine with this code and processed as expected, but when I try to send the 2nd reply back I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "challenge.py", line 28, in <module>
     sock.send(valmis)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

If I do not close or shutdown the socket, no reply is ever sent to server.

How can I tell my client to send the message and wait for reply without socket.shutdown? Or if I need to open new socket for each loop, how should the loop be constructed? The reply from server changes each time so if I open new connection completely and request for data, I get new reply and the process starts from beginning again.

UPDATE: 
the issue seems to be when trying to receive the second reply from server, only the first line of message is received by client.

Comment: I have also tested with sendall(data, MSG_DONTWAIT) which results the same.

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally broken; there is absolutely no reason to believe that a single call to `.recv()` on a TCP stream will get an entire message (there is no correlation between the chunks that are received, and the chunks that were sent at the other end).  ANY protocol that allows multiple messages to be sent over a single connection MUST have some way of delimiting them; typically either a specific character or string that cannot appear in the messages themselves, or a length value that is transmitted before each message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jason. i'll look into adding some kind of buffer but i'm getting the correct data with this recv - sending the reply here is what i'd need help with.

Comment: Irrespective of how the server is coded, I'd remove the 2nd `data = sock.recv(8192)` because that occurs at the top of the `while` loop, which would mean that data is None. My quick test client did not require the `shutdown` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know it does not send anything?  I modified your code a bit (there is something odd in the else: clause, I will come back to that later).

```
import socket

#connection 
ip="localhost"
port=4000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip,port))

while True:

    data = sock.recv(8192)
    if not data: break;
    print data
    if data != None:
        valmis = data
        if valmis == None:
            print "[-] no results"
            break
        else:
            print "[+] sending message... "
            sock.send(valmis) #this never gets sent without
            continue
```

Basically this is a stripped version of your code - no decrypting or external functionality. It just sends back whatever it receives from the server.

Then I ran a "server" with ncat:

```
ncat -l 4000
```

start your program and start typing in lines (1, 2, 3, 4 etc) and this happens at "server". The client promptly echoes my messages back:

```
test@xyzzy:/tmp$ ncat -l 4000
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

And this happens at the client:

```
test@xyzzy:/tmp$ python so.py 
1

[+] sending message... 
2

[+] sending message... 
3

[+] sending message...
```

To me it looks this code works fine.   If the server does not receive your reply, it might be that there is a problem on the server side. It might for example expect a terminator character in the response. Does your `cleanmsg` clean the message too much and for example remove a trailing newline and the server expects to receive one?

There is a problem in your original else clause as you do another `sock.recv()` there. Which means after receiving a reply, you block there to wait for the next message from server and when you do receive one, you will `continue` your loop and hit `sock.recv()` again. The second message was consumed already in your else clause.

This may be intentional if your server somehow acknowledges your decryption. If your protocol is this:

```
server -> client  (request)
client -> server  (decrypted message)
server -> client  (some kind of acknowledgement - unclear from your code)

server -> client  (request 2)
etc.
```

Then you have probably hit the issue in Jason's comment.  TCP sockets are completely agnostic to the concept of a message. They just transmit data. When your code hits `sock.recv()`, one of five things can happen:

1. There is nothing in the socket and the call blocks
2. There is a full "message" and only that in the socket and you receive that
3. There is a partial message and you will receive that. Either because the message is over 8192 bytes, or your code just decides to read when the server has only transmitted some of the message data.
4. There are two or more complete "messages" waiting and you will receive them all.
5. As four, but the last message is partial

Always when operating with TCP sockets, you must cater for scenarios 2-5. You must parse the data, make sure everything is there, and if not, wait for more. And if there was more than you expected, process them accordingly. If they are complete messages, process them. If the last message is partial, process everything else and wait for more.

If messages seem to "disappear" in a self-made communication protocol using TCP sockets, 99% of the problems are caused by making the assumption that sockets would know or care what is the structure of your "message". A very common mistake is to read your socket empty and ignore everything you received after your first message.

Hope this is helpful. Your code without the additional recv seems to work fine from socket communication perspective - no need to shut down the socket. It may be a server side issue, protocol issue or message parsing problem.

For this reason, always have only one `recv` call for your socket. Even if you are expecting some kind of an acknowledgement instead of a new message, have only one place where you process socket data. Then do some kind of a conditional there to detect what kind of a message you received and then decide what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks Hannu! I hadn't actually thought of this - i modified the code as you suggested and also added print statement to the start of the while-loop and it the loop seems to restart fine but no data is received from server end.

The mechanics here is following:
1. when connecting to server it prompts you with some text in encrypted format
2. cleanmsg-function cleans the coming input to leave only encrypted part of the message
3. decryptmsg decrypts that output
4. then you are supposed to send it back to server, if the encryption is broken correct the server sends another message as a rep

Comment: And this is where i hit the problem - i can't seem to tell server that im done with sending and thus there is never a reply.

Comment: I captured the traffic and you are correct - the communications actually work; when following the TCP stream i can see the server replying but it seems that the reply is only partial - in the reply i can only see the first line of the reply and the actual encrypted data never gets back to client, thus the decryption never takes place.

I've updated the original question with new receive code but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: OK - sometimes answer is too near for you to see it - the server was excepting line break "\n" in the answer in addition of the correct message to produce response - now the communication works.

Added your answer as the correct one - thank you!

Comment: This would be the "protocol error" or "stripped newline".  Waiting for a newline in the message forms the basis of this particular protocol.   If I am personally responsible for the client and server, I will almost always use zeromq. It is as simple to use as sockets, and it will raise the abstraction level from bytes to messages. It will take care of transmitting and receiving a message in its entirety. With sockets I just end up writing a lot of donkey code to provide the same functionality.